# How do I limit the size of my Postgres log?

Tags: postgresql, disk-space, log, size

I’m using Postgres 9.5 on Ubuntu 14.04.  I notice I’m generating a lot of Postgres logs in

```
/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log
```

.  I would like to limit the size of this file, and doing some time based rotation (e.g. daily) is not an option.  Is there any way I can tell Postgres to rotate its logs once they reach a certain size?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-ROTATION-SIZE

Answer (score 4):

The [PostgreSQL Error reporting and logging documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-logging.html) states:

> `log_rotation_size (integer)`
>
> When logging_collector is enabled, this parameter determines the maximum size of an individual log file. After this many kilobytes have been emitted into a log file, a new log file will be created. Set to zero to disable size-based creation of new log files. This parameter can only be set in the postgresql.conf file or on the server command line.

So, I guess you should set this parameter to the desired value. My `postgresql.conf` option has the default values:

```
#log_rotation_size = 10MB       # Automatic rotation of logfiles will  
                # happen after that much log output.  
                # 0 disables.
```

Comment: I set this but it is still not rotating the logs .. maybe I there is something else I need to do besides restarting the PostGres server?

Comment: Is `logging_collector`  enabled ?